# Simple way to dynamically replace placeholder with value at Groovy strings

Tags: string, groovy, placeholder

I'm trying to find laconic and efficient way to replace placeholders with values at the Groovy Strings. But I can't find convenient solution for 2 cases:

1. When String with the placeholder and the value are defined at different classes.
2. When the String is passed as argument to a method, and should be replaced with local's variable value. Here is the illustration of 2 approaches I have tried:

   ```
     class A {
         static def strPlaceHolder = 'token = ${tokenValue}';
         static def strRefPlaceHolder = "token = ${->tokenRef}";
     }

     class B {
         def tokenRef = "token reference as field";

         void parseGString(GString str) {
             println str; //fails here. No property tokenRef for class: A. Though I've expected that "this" is B
         }

         void parseString(String str) {
             def tokenValue = "token value as local variable";
             println str; //I know why it doesn't work as required. But how to make something similar
         }

     }

     new B().parseString(A.strPlaceHolder); //token = ${tokenValue}
     new B().parseGString(A.strRefPlaceHolder); //fails,
   ```

Comment: What are you expecting as result with `${->tokenRef}`?

Comment: Ernest, iwas expecting to be replaced with this.tokenRef at the time when GString is transformed to String. 

And it works like this in some cases, in Script environment. But in this cases, with POJO classes.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele the `${-> x}` will do a late evaluation of X (only when it has to manifest itself to a string

Comment: Ernest, thanks, it's a better explanation of the `${-> }` syntax. But anyway, in the example, when it performs later evaluation in the class B, where value is available, it looks for the value at the class A, where GStrng was defined.

Comment: thank you, Josh Sullivan

Answer (score 3):

You could replace your GString fields with closures and pass those closures to your methods. e.g.:

```
class A {
    static def strPlaceHolder = { token -> "token = ${token}" }
}

class B {
    def tokenRef = "token reference as field";

    void parseGString(def closure) {
        println closure(tokenRef)
    }

    void parseString(def closure) {
        def tokenValue = "token value as local variable"
        println closure(tokenValue)
    }
}
new B().parseString(A.strPlaceHolder);
new B().parseGString(A.strPlaceHolder);
```